# Add column with unique identifiers for new data but maintain unique identifiers for previous data in python

Tags: python, bash

I have a tsv file (column 1 = unique id, column 2 = group association) that looks like this:

```
BC187   1 
L1374   1
YJM1332 1
YPS128  2 
YPS606  2
YJM1273 2
UWOPS03.461.4   3 
UWOPS05.217.3   3
UWOPS05.227.2   3
```

Essentially BC187, L1374, and YJM1332 all belong to group 1, etc.

and I generate output that is another list of unique individuals like so:

```
Y12
DBVPG604
GE14S01.7B
```

I can append this second list to the tsv file via:

```
with open('~/clade.file.txt', 'a') as f:
divergedstrain.to_csv(f, header = False, index = False)
```

to get the list below:

```
BC187   1 
L1374   1
YJM1332 1
YPS128  2 
YPS606  2
YJM1273 2
UWOPS03.461.4   3 
UWOPS05.217.3   3
UWOPS05.227.2   3
Y12
DBVPG604
GE14S01.7B
```

But now I need to give the three new unique individuals (Y12, DBVPG604, GE14S01.7B) their own unique association like so:

```
BC187   1 
L1374   1
YJM1332 1
YPS128  2 
YPS606  2
YJM1273 2
UWOPS03.461.4   3 
UWOPS05.217.3   3
UWOPS05.227.2   3
Y12   4 
DBVPG604   5
GE14S01.7B 6
```

I am not sure what the best way to do this either via python or bash. Any suggestions

Comment: What makes elements unique and what makes them be part of the same group? How do we know that the new values appended don't belong to a previous group, or if they share groups among themselves?

Comment: Hi @Perplexabot! Thanks for the solution, working through it now. You pose a great question and is another aspect of the issue I am working on. In the above instance though, I am using genetic sequence differences to determine how diverged an individual is from the previously defined set (e.g. BC187 through UWOPS05.227.2). So above the individuals (Y12, DBVPG604, and GE14S01.7B) are all considered diverged based on a test and thus are unique. But to add individuals which are most similar to other previously defined groups is the next step :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
from pandas import DataFrame as df
from pandas import read_csv

file_path = 'clade.file.txt'

divergedstrain = df(["Y12", "DBVPG604", "GE14S01.7B", "Y12"])
with open(file_path, 'a') as f:
    divergedstrain.to_csv(f, header=False, index=False)

df = read_csv(file_path, header=None, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=[0, 1])

ids = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row[0] not in ids and row[1] == row[1]:
        ids[row[0]] = row[1]


def set_and_save(curr_row):
    if curr_row[1] != curr_row[1]:
        if curr_row[0] in ids:
            curr_row[1] = ids[curr_row[0]]
        else:
            new_id = max(ids.values()) + 1
            ids[curr_row[0]] = new_id
            curr_row[1] = new_id
    return curr_row


df = df.apply(set_and_save, axis=1)
print(df)
```

The output:

```
                0    1
0           BC187  1.0
1           L1374  1.0
2         YJM1332  1.0
3          YPS128  2.0
4          YPS606  2.0
5         YJM1273  2.0
6   UWOPS03.461.4  3.0
7   UWOPS05.217.3  3.0
8   UWOPS05.227.2  3.0
9             Y12  4.0
10       DBVPG604  5.0
11     GE14S01.7B  6.0
12            Y12  4.0
```

Comment: `set_and_save` could be simplified/modified depending on your needs. I have set it as it is now so that if two sequences are identical (not sure if that is a case) they get the same id (that is the reason for the `ids` dictionary).